# Screen flickering on 18.04 ubuntu dual-boot

Tags: dual-boot, screen

So i just dual booted my razer blade stealth with ubuntu 18.04 and the screen kept on flickering. I solved it by changing the screen options to a lower resolution. But whenever i close my laptop, and open it again the same problem occours, and I will have to reboot my laptop...

Any solutions to this? I am a linux newby so please be specific:)